# Merge second level of array based on top level (shared values)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I want to merge the top level of the array, such that all the values of the second level sharing the same parent form a single array to that parent.

Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C1
            [1] => C1
            [2] => C1
            [3] => AC
            [4] => AC
        )

)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C1_complete
            [1] => C1_29-95
            [2] => C1_49-95
            [3] => AC_complete
            [4] => AC_29-95
        )

)
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            'C1' => Array (C1_complete, C1_29-95, C1_49-95),
            'AC' => Array (AC_complete, AC_29-95)
        )

)
```

What is a simple, elegant way to achieve this?

I seek a solution that could generalise the same principle to any two-level array structure.

Comment: How understand that C1== com1... ?

Comment: Sorry - fixed now - that was a typo.

Comment: You didn't fix the desired result.

Comment: Begging your pardon, sirs - fixed now.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense. 

Comment: Are your arrays always going to be in equal length?

Comment: Another question is: Does your top level array always contain just one entry?

Comment: @Innervisions No, array lengths can vary.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes - the top level only contains one entry.

Comment: I think Innervisions means: Are array 1 and array 2 always of the same length? We understand that the number of entries in both can vary. But if array 1 has 10 entries then array 2 will also have 10 entries?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, that's correct.  The first and second arrays will always have the same number of entries.

Comment: Why do you need array 1, since all the information seems present in array 2?

Comment: @user136649 did you try foreach?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  If you can achieve the result from just Array 2, then it would be satisfactory to ignore Array 1.

Comment: Actually why don't we make this more challenging.  Let's assume the columns are what align and that Array 2 does not contain the prefix which makes Array 1 redundant.  That is Array1[2] aligns with Array2[2].

Comment: Your solution with just Array 2 is fine as long as it works, I can't run it right now, but I will run it at the first opportunity to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I only use array 2, and a simple `foreach` loop, I can do it this way:

```
$array2 = [['C1_complete', 
            'C1_29-95',
            'C1_49-95',
            'AC_complete',
            'AC_29-95']];

$buffer = [];

foreach ($array2[0] as $value) {
    $buffer[substr($value, 0, 2)][] = $value;
}

$result[] = $buffer;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [C1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C1_complete
                    [1] => C1_29-95
                    [2] => C1_49-95
                )

            [AC] => Array
                (
                    [0] => AC_complete
                    [1] => AC_29-95
                )

        )

)
```

It's nice if that code is in a function:

```
function classify($array)
{    
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array[0] as $value) {
        $result[substr($value, 0, 2)][] = $value;
    }
    return [$result];
}    

$array2 = [['C1_complete', 
            'C1_29-95',
            'C1_49-95',
            'AC_complete',
            'AC_29-95']];

echo '<pre>';
print_r(classify($array2));
echo '</pre>';
```

The output stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your arrays you don't need the first loop, but if you have multiple arrays in your array.  Just loop and grep for items starting with the key:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $inner) {
    foreach($inner as $k) {
        $result[$key][$k] = preg_grep("/^$k/", $array2[0]);
    }
}
```

With your given arrays:

```
foreach($array1[0] as $k) {
    $result[0][$k] = preg_grep("/^$k/", $array2[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did upvote you - I'm new so my upvotes don't publicly show

Comment: Actually, this won't work. If you change `$array2` to `$array2[0]` then it does work. An explanation would be nice.

Comment: `foreach($array1[0] as $k) $result[0][$k] = preg_grep("/^$k/", $array2[0]);` would also work...

Comment: I removed my downvote. This is not an efficient solution, but it is (possible) very short. I didn't know `preg_grep()` could filter an array, but it is useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both `simple` and `elegant` way seems very unlikely to me in this case as this might be opinion based. A simple foreach is the most easy and efficient way to achieve this. However, for elegancy, you can use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) and [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to achieve this.

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array(
    Array
        (
            'C1',
            'C1',
            'C1',
            'AC',
            'AC'
    )
);

$arr2 = Array(
    Array(
            'C1_complete',
            'C1_29-95',
            'C1_49-95',
            'AC_complete',
            'AC_29-95'
    )
);


$data = array_combine(array_values($arr1[0]),array_fill(0,count($arr1[0]),[]));

array_walk($arr2[0],function($value) use (&$data){
    if(isset($data[explode("_",$value)[0]])) $data[explode("_",$value)[0]][] = $value;
});

$data = [$data]; // since you want it inside another array.

print_r($data);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/VhFLH7

Comment: Wow, this solution is quite instructive at a higher level - I thank you, Sir for your enlightening input!  Upvoted.